# getting http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client when consul-template is trying to retrieve healthy nodes

Tags: consul, consul-template

In our infrastructure, we have cluster of app nodes with consul service running as `consul server` component.
There is also another cluster of proxy nodes which have `consul-template` service installed. This `consul-template` has configuration which is used to discover the healthy app nodes and update the proxy config file.

We are using `chef` to provision our infra. The app nodes were configured properly. Consul service on these nodes is working as expected.

But on the proxy nodes when the `consultemplate` service is trying to start I see the following WARN in the messages log file:

```
[WARN] (view) catalog.datacenters: Get https://<app_nodes_consul_service_ip>/v1/catalog/datacenters: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client (retry attempt 5 after "4s")
```

I am not sure what config on the app nodes - consul service I need to check to see why its responding as HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I dont want to change this to HTTP in the lower env as I want the chef cookbooks to be consistent across the envs including the HTTPS connecivtities.

Any pointers on which config I need to check would be of great help.